# ZedGraph изменение цвета линейки на осях

Tags: c#, zedgraph

Как изменить цвет линейки на осях? Сам бордюр меняется, а вот риски линейки так и остаются чёрными.

Подскажите параметр содержащий в себе свойство этого цвета.

Comment: Дайте код, который можно попробовать. Подозреваю вам нужно свойство http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/default.html

Comment: Вот [тут](http://jenyay.net/ZedGraph/AxisColor) есть пример. Но в нём нет того что мне нужно. У меня фон чёрный и для графика и для всего элемента. Границы графика зелёные, сетка серая, графики красный и синий. Вот [пример](http://joxi.ru/E2pVNqaF9PoQWr) моего графика, но в нём нет линейки на осях т.к. она чёрная.

Comment: с `pane.XAxis.Color` поэкспериментируйте, по ссылке устанавливается серый цвет там

Comment: @АндрейNOP, К сожалению [не оно](http://joxi.ru/8AnG7qKijPvezr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Риски на линейке называются соответственно `MinorTic` и `MajorTic` (тики?), задайте цвет им:

```
commonGraph.GraphPane.XAxis.MinorTic.Color = Color.Reg;
commonGraph.GraphPane.XAxis.MajorTic.Color = Color.Green;
commonGraph.GraphPane.YAxis.MinorTic.Color = Color.Blue;
commonGraph.GraphPane.YAxis.MajorTic.Color = Color.Yellow;
```

Comment: Спасибо. То что [нужно](http://joxi.ru/LmG8dMwfeoXJR2). Даже в голову не могло прийти, что деления линейки называются **Tic**.

Comment: @Rootware, пожалуйста, рад помочь